# Find unique array of string patterns that exist in a text

Tags: c#, regex, string, performance

I'd like to get a `string[]` of the *searchStrings* that exist in a multiline text.

```
string[] searchStrings = {"Fizz", "Buzz", "Foo", "Bar"}
```

Each of the search strings *must* be preceded by `:`,`,` or `.`, and followed by `!` or `?`

The actual search list could be up to 100 strings

And my text looks like this (but the text could be up to 100,000 lines), where `Fizz`, `Buzz` and `Foo` all occur multiple times, and `Bar` doesn't occur at all:

> Lorem ipsum dolor **,Fizz!** amet,  consectetur adipiscing elit.  Nulla
>
> laoreet **.Fizz!** facilisis.  Mauris **:Buzz!** efficitur nisi. Morbi
>
> consectetur hendrerit pretium. Ut  tempor mauris **,Buzz!** consequat
>
> convallis. Quisque lacinia felis in ex lacinia,  luctus malesuada
>
> purus tristique.  Nullam tincidunt dolor sit amet metus  vehicula, Foo
>
> amet fringilla lacus ultrices. Maecenas semper **.Fizz!** le justo molestie,
>
> non ultrices Buzz! consequat.  Donec **:Foo?** facilisis tellus.  Nunc
>
> pulvinar egestas turpis. Donec sed ex rhoncus, Fizz dolor eget,
>
> aliquam  orci.**.Foo!** tincidunt pellentesque  dolor sed mollis.

Given that example, I'd like to return `{"Fizz","Buzz","Foo"}`

I'm seeking performance over elegance.

I'm assuming that regex will be my best option, but I'm unsure whether to:

- Return a match collection of *all* instances using a pattern like:

  `[,.:]+(Fizz|Buzz|Foo|Bar)[?!]`

  and then find the unique matches
- Loop over each search string and use something like:

  `Regex.IsMatch(text, string.Format("[,.:]{0}[?!]", searchStrings[i]))`
- Or maybe there's some Regex construct that I'm unaware of that will return the first instance of each search string?

Given that finding unique matches could be time consuming, I'm inclined to think that the `IsMatch` approach will be the fastest approach.

Comment: So you already know that there will be some combination of Fizz, Buzz, Foo, and or Bar from the start, or you don't know what is between the [,.:] and [?!] and you have to find all the distinct matches?

Comment: I know I'm looking for Fizz, Buzz, Foo, and or Bar, but I don't know if I'll find any of them. I just want to know the ones that exist. I don't need to know their locations or frequencies, or what the actual prefix/suffix match was.

Comment: Then yeah, the `IsMatch` is the option I'd go with if there number of possible matches is small.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on exact data distribution, but most likely loop over each searchs is a bad idea. You definitely do not want to go through the very big string over and over again. Lets make some simple benchmark. Build some dummy data:

```
string lorem = @"Lorem ipsum dolor ,Fizz! amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Nulla
laoreet .Fizz! facilisis. Mauris :Buzz! efficitur nisi. Morbi
consectetur hendrerit pretium. Ut tempor mauris ,Buzz! consequat
convallis. Quisque lacinia felis in ex lacinia, luctus malesuada
purus tristique. Nullam tincidunt dolor sit amet metus vehicula, Foo
amet fringilla lacus ultrices. Maecenas semper .Fizz! le justo molestie,
non ultrices Buzz! consequat. Donec :Foo? facilisis tellus. Nunc
pulvinar egestas turpis. Donec sed ex rhoncus, Fizz dolor eget,
aliquam orci..Foo! tincidunt pellentesque dolor sed mollis.";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
{
    sb.Append(lorem);
}

int lensb = sb.Length;
Random rnd = new Random(1);
for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
{
    sb[rnd.Next(lensb)] = '!';
    sb[rnd.Next(lensb)] = '?';
    sb[rnd.Next(lensb)] = '.';
    sb[rnd.Next(lensb)] = ',';
    sb[rnd.Next(lensb)] = ':';
    sb[rnd.Next(lensb)] = lorem[rnd.Next(lorem.Length)];
}

string sample = sb.ToString();
```

And do a test

```
Regex r = new Regex("[,.:](Fizz|Buzz|Foo|Bar|eeeeeeeeeo|kjkjsh|iousadh|kjlsadh|jfsfs|sdfs)[?!]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
HashSet<string> matches = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (Match match in r.Matches(sample))
{
    matches.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
}//240ms
```

not bad. And now the loops:

```
List<string> matches = new List<string>();
foreach (string s in new string[] { "Fizz", "Buzz", "Foo", "Bar", "eeeeeeeeeo", "kjkjsh", "iousadh", "kjlsadh", "jfsfs", "sdfs" })
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(sample, "[,.:]" + s + "[?!]", RegexOptions.Compiled))
    {
        matches.Add(s);
    }
}//890ms
```

as expected, slower. But regex is probably not the top performant option here. If You really need performance, I would go with something like

```
enum State { NA, DOT, STR };

HashSet<string> ok = new HashSet<string>() { "Fizz", "Buzz", "Foo", "Bar", "eeeeeeeeeo", "kjkjsh", "iousadh", "kjlsadh", "jfsfs", "sdfs" };
List<string> matches = new List<string>();
int len = sample.Length;
int start = -1;
State state = State.NA;
for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    char c = sample[i];
    switch (state)
    {
        case State.NA:
            if (c == '.' || c == ',' || c == ':')
            {
                start = i;
                state = State.DOT;
            }
            break;
        case State.DOT:
            if (c == '.' || c == ',' || c == ':')
            {
                start = i;
                continue;
            }
            if (c == '!' || c == '?')
            {
                state = State.NA;
                continue;
            }
            state = State.STR;
            break;
        case State.STR:
            if (c == '.' || c == ',' || c == ':')
            {
                start = i;
                state = State.DOT;
                continue;
            }
            if (c == '!' || c == '?')
            {
                state = State.NA;
                string substr = sample.Substring(start + 1, i - start - 1);
                if (ok.Contains(substr))
                {
                    matches.Add(substr);
                    ok.Remove(substr);
                }
                continue;
            }
            break;
    }
}//30ms
```

Comment: interesting. I wonder how the strategy might change if the text were an array of short strings, each string an average of 20-30 characters in length, some empty, some shorter, some longer, instead of one big string?

Comment: I guess in that case the loops approach improves memory locality, but loses advantage of the short circuiting. The test says the result is slower. The timing I measured was 120ms, 660ms and 20ms for 100000 samples 0-50 characters, I just changed matches to HashSet and do not alter `ok` in the last code. To be honest I am not sure why the handcrafted state automate is that much faster than regex here, probably the regex implementation is somewhat inefficient here. But as always, i would rather retest the timing on real data.